# Closing the app automatically after copy completion?

Tags: vb.net

I want to make an application to copy files from flashdrive to my computer (2-6GB).
The problem is, I want my application to close automatically after finishing copy the files to computer.

What code should I add?

```
Dim Source As String = (GetDriveLetterFromMask(Volume.dbcv_unitmask) & ":\")
Dim Destination As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\Backup" 'This Is The Destination Folder (My Documents\Backup\*.*)
                            'Loop All Files And Folders To Copy Everything
For Each strFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Source, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")
Dim strFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFile) 'Get File Name From File Path
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strFile, Destination & strFileName)
```

Comment: Please mark my answer as answer if it helped,so that in future,Others find it helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be achieved using a `BackGroundWorker`.

[Learn more about BackGroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

Just add your code to the `DoWork` event of the `BackGroundWorker` and in the `RunWorkerCompleted` Event,add this :

```
 Me.Close 'or you can use Application.Exit
```

**The full code**

Firstly,you can add a backgroundworker from from the toolbox(just double-click on the BackGroundWorker control from toolbox to add it).Now,when the backgroundworker is added,you can see the Background worker in the bottom left conrner of visual Studio window(the default name is BackGroundWorker1).Double click on backgroundwoker1 and it'll take you to the CODE window where the `DoWork` event would be Pre-selected.

Now let's code!!

```
'To start the backgroundWorker

 Public Sub Btn_click
 BackGroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

 'Adding the code the `Dowork`event
 Public Sub BackgroundWOrker1_DoWork

 Dim Source As String = (GetDriveLetterFromMask(Volume.dbcv_unitmask) & 
 ":\")
 Dim Destination As String = 
 My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\Backup" 'This Is 
 The Destination Folder (My Documents\Backup\*.*)
                        'Loop All Files And Folders To Copy Everything
 For Each strFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(Source, 
 FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.*")
 Dim strFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFile) 'Get File 
 Name From File Path
 My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(strFile, Destination & strFileName) 

 'Firing the RunWorkerCompleted Event(or should i say closing the app when the worker is done working)

 Public Sub BackGroundworker1_RunworkerCompleted()

 Me.Close 'or you can use Application.exit(NOTE: Application.Exit is obsolete)
```

I guess that's all you need for now.

For more details,follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv4FdoaUMQE)

Comment: 'Thankyou' But I'm confused, how to add it?

Comment: Cool thank you very much Zack !
My email yume.seekaaii@gmail.com, Maybe I can ask more? ww

Comment: anytime...bruh [by chatting here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164029/sharing-knowledgevb-net-c-wpf-xaml)